# how to read a string from string.xml and use the same in an activity?

Tags: android

i have a key value pair in String.xml as - 
key - feedback
value - your feedback is valuable.

How can I pull the same that value within the programme? I want to use the same in a toast message to notify user.

edit: My application is supposed to support different languages. how can I pick up the value of a string of contextual language? Can I use getString() method to pick up a translated value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this-> `getResources.getString(R.string.feedback);`

For Toast message ->

```
Toast.makeText(this, getResources.getString(R.string.feedback), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

String feedback = getString(R.string.feedback);

Comment: thanks. it worked for me -getBasecontext().getString(R.string.fedback) found it here as well - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html. thanks again.

Comment: If the code is in an activity you do not need getBaseContext().